# How to display image in crystal report?

Tags: image, crystal-reports

I have created a new .rpt file. Right click on section 3 and there added a picture. It shows nicely in the editor (Visual Studio 2008) but when I generate the report as a pdf file then I do not get to see the image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may depend on the image file.  If you Select All in the pdf, do you see the outline of the image?

Comment: I see the whole image yes. Strange thing is that it seems I can get it to be viewed when I turn down the dpi from 300 to 100. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by editing my `Web.Config` file and inserting the following line:

```
<system.web>
...
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" verb="GET"
    type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web,
    Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"></add>
</httpHandlers>
...
```

N.B. take care with your version number (i.e. Version=xx.x.xxxx.x)